# php mysql adds forward slash on sql insert from array

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting values checked from a form into a db, but the inserted value has a slash (/) at the end.

I am inserting into sql database from an array in a form with check boxes, I want to insert only the checked values.

The insert is okay for all the values but they appear with a slash at the end  and I can't tell why it is like that.

Here is the form

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="add_payroll.php">
<label>Employees</label><br>

<?php
// include "../includes/connect.php";
$cs = mysql_query("SELECT user_Idnum, salary, user_fname, user_lname,user_mname from tbl_user_details");

if($cs==true){
$count=mysql_num_rows($cs);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($cs)){
extract($row);
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="detail_Id[]" value='.$user_Idnum.'/>'.$user_fname." ".$user_mname." ".$user_lname.'<br>';

 }
 }
?>                                       
<label>Description</label>

<textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
<label>Transaction Date</label>
<input size="16" type="text"  readonly name="transaction_date"class="form_datetime form-control">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn dark btn-outline">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

And here is the php script

```
<?php
include "../functions/connect.php";
$ids  = $_POST['detail_Id'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];
$time = $_POST['transaction_date'];

foreach ($ids as  $va) {

$run1= mysql_query("insert into tbl_payroll(detail_Id, description,     transaction_date) values('$va', '$desc', '$time' )");

                            if($run1==true)
                             {
                                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                                echo 'alert("Successfully Added")';
                                echo '</script>';
                                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=report.php" />';
                             }

    }

?>
```

Comment: `value='.$user_Idnum.'/` perhaps? Use quotes.

Comment: yess..... Jon Stirling.... thats where the problem was....

Comment: This code demonstrates everything you shouldn't do when querying a database.  First off you're using mysql_* functions which are hopelessly out of date and been deprecated for years, and are no longer even present in PHP 7.  Second off, you're building queries by concatenating strings instead of using parameterised statements.  Third off you're accepting user input without any kind of validation or sanitation.  This code is a recipe for disaster.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="detail_Id[]" value='.$user_Idnum.'/>'.$user_fname." ".$user_mname." ".$user_lname.'<br>';
```

To

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="detail_Id[]" value="'.$user_Idnum.'"/>'.$user_fname." ".$user_mname." ".$user_lname.'<br>';
```

By having no quotes around the value attribute whatever is within that value will have a trailing slash concatenated to it's value.

You should probably not be writing out the javascript and meta-refresh in a loop either - the refresh will be triggered on the first iteration through the loop and subsequent statements will not be executed.

Also worth noting is the use of the now deprecated `mysql` functions - upgrade to either `mysqli` or `PDO` and use `prepared statements` to prevent SQL injection, something to which this code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include "../functions/connect.php";
$ids  = $_POST['detail_Id'];
```

try

```
if(substr($ids, -1) == '/') {
   $ids = substr($ids, 0, -1);
}
```

or

```
$ids = rtrim($ids,"/");
```

..

```
$desc = $_POST['description'];
$time = $_POST['transaction_date'];
.......
```